# Should I use 'is' or 'are' in this sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Should I use 'is' or 'are' in this sentence?

> - Are Joyce and I going to finish the posters?
> - Is Joyce and I going to finish the posters?

Answer (score 4):

You should use *are*. Your sentence has two subjects, *Joyce* and *I*, therefore any verb referring to them should be in the plural form. One way to think about it is that you could replace *Joyce* and *I* with *we*:

> We are going to finish the posters.

In this case, it is even clearer that *are* should be used.

Answer (score -4):

you should use 'is' in fact that it refers to joyce as the one who is going to finish the posters with someone else. you can use are in this case: Are we going to finish the posters? due to we refers both subjects.

Comment: Actually, there are two people (Joyce and I) who are finishing the posters, so your answer here is incorrect.